# Weird contextual ActionBar on opening

Tags: java, android, contextual-action-bar

My CAB behaves strangely on opening, I can't explain... so [here's a link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rpb8uw6dru7bigs/listviewCAB.apk) to the APK, then you'll be able to see what I mean.

Here's the sample code I used : http://www.technotalkative.com/contextual-action-bar-cab-android/

I've noticed that it does not happen everytime, but when it happens, it happens once and not twice. I don't know where it comes from...

**Edit :** I found a software which creates GIF, so here's a GIF of the weird behaviour (refresh to see it once again) :

[image]

Comment: please remove the apk link...and post the screenshot of result what you got and what you were expecting along with the code.

Comment: I'm very sorry but I can't, because it happens during less than a second...